# LibGdx unable to launch app on iOs emulator

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, libgdx, robovm

first of all sorry if this is a duplicate question, I didn't find anything about my problem.
So, I bought a MaC Mini and I want to figure out how can I run my libgdx app on the iOs emulator.
I downloaded all the sofware and updated it : last version of Eclipse, downloaded the RoboVM fork from MobiDevelop (since the official Robo VM plugin no longer exists) and imported my project into Eclipse. I also have got the last Xcode version.
I figured out how to successfully build the iOs project but the problem is that when the app needs to start, I get an error which I'm not able to understand :

```
    2016-10-31 14:56:27.786 simlauncher[1727:91648] +[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1111a1118
2016-10-31 14:56:27.798 simlauncher[1727:91648] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SimDeviceSet defaultSet]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1111a1118'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff878336fb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9c03aa2a objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff878b3c04 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff877a6f03 ___forwarding___ + 1059
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff877a6a58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   simlauncher                         0x000000010deeb21d getSimDevice + 53
    6   simlauncher                         0x000000010deeadbb moe_main + 569
    7   simlauncher                         0x000000010deeab5c main + 275
    8   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9c917255 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think the problem is that robovm doesn't find the emulator that is opened while trying to start the app.

Comment: Have you find any solutions for this? Because i also face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Couple weeks ago everything was fine, but yesterday I tried to run simulator and I had the same exception as you... What I remember is that I upgraded my XCode to 8.1 version. So I deleted my current XCode 8.1 and then I installed XCode 8. After that simulator works fine. I don't know if this is 8.1 version issue - maybe simple reinstall is sufficient. How to downgrade XCode?

1. Uninstall your actual XCode - right click on the XCode icon in Applications and click "Move to trash"
2. Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/index.html site, login, go to bottom of the site and click "See more downloaods".
3. Select XCode 8 from the list, download and install.
4. Reboot system